# how are these two function signatures passed to then() equivalent?

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
async function f() {
  return 2
}

//example A
f().then( d => console.log(d) ) //output = 2

//example B
f().then(console.log) //output = 2
```

In example A, the result (the number 2) is passed in as the variable d. This is just a basic fat arrow function.

In example B, the result (the number 2) seems to be magically put into console.log. What is the underlying mechanism by which the number 2 makes it into console.log(2)?

Comment: How do you think the value gets assigned to `d` in the arrow function? You can pass any function to `.then` and it will be fed the resolution value of the promise.

Comment: `.then` takes a function. `console.log` is a function. So is `d => console.log(d)`. And they happen to be the same function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The then takes in a callback as it's argument and will pass in the result as the parameter.

So essentially //example A
`f().then( d => console.log(d) ) //output = 2`
Is the same as

`const myFunc = d => console.log(d);`

`f().then( myFunct ) //output = 2`

When passing in the arrow function you're creating that callback inline. Even here the parameter is not actually referring to the result as much as setting the parameter for the function being created.

When passing in console.log your assigning the console.log function as the callback.

Comment: ah. my error was thinking then is passed the result. It is not. It is passed the callback function. then just passes the callback function the result. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) of *then*:
*The then() method returns a Promise. It takes up to **two** arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise*.

So in the first example you are providing as resolve argument the function :

```
(d) => {
        console.log(d);
       }
```

In the second one you are providing as resolve argument the function:

```
console.log
```

Both function are called with the return value of the async function f(): 2. In case of error, you're not providing a reject argument, so no function will be called and the code will fail.

Answer (score 1):

console.log is a function. and the value that returns after .then() will be passed into the function that comes in it; the function is console.log in your case. They are the same if you're just printing the value, but the second one is neater! Plus you can't provide the reject variable in the second case.